# How long will last the CBMR?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I am confused about the duration of the cosmic background microwave radiation.Will it eventually be replaced by same radiation from discrete directions?

Comment: Why do you think it would come from discrete directions? What would be special about those directions?

Comment: @G.Smith  As the primordial universe started being inhomogenous in matter density and first locations with no matter that would not emit that radiation appeared.

Comment: @JankoBradvica - You might be thinking that we are seeing radiation from exactly X years back, which of course should be changing as the universe back then changed. But remember that each year we get photons that were traveling from one lightyear further away: we still see the CMB from the era of last scattering, which is pretty homogeneous.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Should we see some decrease in intensity of cbmr as some portion of that distant space is falling out the observable universe.We should see some evolution of that distant space at very past time.?

Comment: @JankoBradvica - No. The CMB is the photons released when the original plasma recombined ~300,000 years after the big bang. Behind the ones you get right now there are others, released at the same time but further away. There is a redshift that is increasing with time due to the expansion of the universe, but there was not much evolution going on during that era.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Is CMB the picture of the universe before first gravitational agregations and before first parts of space being free of any matter (voids)?....

Comment: @JankoBradvica - CMB is basically the picture of the universe at the time of "the surface of last scattering" when everything stopped being plasma. There were no voids, although there was enough lumpiness to indicate where voids would emerge later.

Comment: @AndersSandberg One more question:If the most distant objects from as are to be unobservable in the future will it be the same with CMB?Or it arrives to us not only from all directions but also from all distances?

Comment: @JankoBradvica - It arrives from all directions and distances so technically it will always be there, but the redshifting will gradually make it unobservable.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Ok. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The current model of the expansion of the universe is dominated by $\Omega_{\Lambda}$. In the distance future

1-$\Omega_{\Lambda}$ << 1.

At this era the expansion of the universe will become exponential, and at some point the temperature of the CMB will become less than the temperature of Hawking radiation of black holes. When that happens, near a black hole the radiation will become mostly the Hawking radiation.

I will later calculate the time when this happens.

ADDED

Step 1. In the future, the scale factor (a) gets larger, and in the Friedmann equation with four $\Omega$s (with subscripts: R, M, k, and $\Lambda$) have the following approximate values.

$\Omega_{\Lambda}$ ~ 1, and the other 3 $\Omega$s << 1.

Assuming a=10 (z=-0.9) should be adequate for this purpose.  The corresponding time (since the big bang) is

(Eq 1) $t_1 = 51 Gyr$.

This is calculated using

[http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/CosmoCalc.html](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/%7Ewright/CosmoCalc.html)

with $H_0$=70 (km/s)Mpc (1/$H_0$~14 Gyr) and $\Omega_m$=0.315. Note: the corresponding value of $1/H(t_1)$ is

$$(Eq 2) \frac {1} {H(t_1)} = 0.8 Gyr.$$

So the Friedmann equation for $t > t_1$ becomes (approximately)

$$(Eq 3) H(t) = \frac {da/dt} {a} = \frac {1} {0.8 Gyr}$$

Step 2: (TO BE COMPLETED - NEEDS INPUT FROM @Janko Bradvica) Select a value for the mass of a black hole to use for the remainder of the discussion.

I want to develop the answer to the question considering only a single value for the mass of a black hole. Three are three plausible choices.  I would like Janko to choose one.

(a) The black hole at the center of the Milky Way. This is the simplest, but also the most likely to be unrealistic.

(b) A black hole with the total mass of the Milky Way (including dark matter). This is moderately realistic and only moderately complicated.

(c) A black hole with the total mass of the Local galaxy cluster (which contains the Milky Way including dark matter). This is the most realistic, but also the most complicated.

Step 3. The remainder of the work will involve solving (Eq 3) and calculating a value for $t_2$ (time when the black hole temperature is greater than the CMB temperature) and $a(t_2)$, and then corresponding values for the temperatures $T_{CMB}(t_2)$ and $T_{Hawking}(t_2)$.